# Need to Install Specfic version (4.5) of Sonarqube in linux

Tags: installation, sonarqube

I Specifcally need to install a version of 4.5.2 of SonarQube in Linux System.
I dont wnat the latest Version.

Comment: You forgot to add a question. If your question is: "where do I find this version?" please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

Try below link to install SQ 4.5.2, if that's your question.
http://downloads.sonarsource.com/sonarqube/sonarqube-4.5.2.zip